# Optional for nullable types?

Tags: java, kotlin, jackson, option-type, nullable

Is it possible to somehow pass nullable types to Optional?
Example:

```
class X(
    val x: Optional<Int?>
)
```

### why?

I want to serialize this the following way:

```
X(Optional.of(1)) -> {"x":1}
X(Optional.of(null)) -> {"x":null} // <- throws
X(Optional.empty()) -> {}
```

### notice

I've found out that it's possible to do what I want with double Optional, like this:

```
class X(
    val x: Optional<Optional<String>>
)
```

But it'd still be interesting if there's a way with Kotlins nullable types or to know why there's not.

Comment: `Optional.ofNullable`

Comment: `Optional.of(null)` will throw NPE

Comment: This `Optional<Int>?` should do. Even though I'd suggest defining some ad-hoc classes to express that behaviour.

Answer (score 1):

Having `val x: Optional<Int?>` is not advised, as you cannot create an Optional container with a `null` value in it by its definition, and you would encounter a NPE if you try to create an Optional with `Optional.of(null)`. `Optional.of(value)` takes in a non-nullable value ([doc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Optional.html#of-T-)) and `Optional.ofNullable(value)` can take in a nullable value, but would return an empty `Optional` ([doc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Optional.html#ofNullable-T-)).

If you want to be able to serialize the below way

```
X(Optional.of(1)) -> {"x":{"present":true}}
X(null) -> {"x":null}
```

you may define the class as below

```
class X(
    val x: Optional<Int>?
)
```

The tricky part is to be able to serialize as below

```
X(Optional.empty()) -> {}
```

Since by default, Jackson will serialize it as `{"x":{"present":false}}`. The only option that you have to avoid that is to register `Jdk8Module` ([source](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-datatype-jdk8/blob/master/src/main/java/com/fasterxml/jackson/datatype/jdk8/Jdk8Module.java)) with `jackson-datatype-jdk8` dependency in `ObjectMapper` by

```
val mapper = ObjectMapper()
val jdk8Module = Jdk8Module()
jdk8Module.configureAbsentsAsNulls(true)
mapper.registerModule(jdk8Module)
```

But this would treat an empty Optional as Java null thereby serializing as below

```
X(Optional.empty()) -> {"x":null}
X(Optional.of(1)) -> {"x":1}
```

`Optional.ofNullable(value)` with `null` as `value` would behave similar to `Optional.empty()` as both would return an empty `Optional`.

The only way to get `X(Optional.empty()) -> {}` would be by annotating the field with `@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)`, but that would also mean that you'd get the serialization `X(null) -> {}`